# When can composition of functions break?

Tags: functional-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

Are there circumstances which may arise within, say, functional analysis where one's able to evaluate a composition of functions by only **first** evaluating the functions under composition obtaining real numbers and then, **only after**, map these real numbers to another real number by means of a third function? Which is to say a circumstance where evaluating a composition of functions as an **aggregate** produces different answers than when that same composition is evaluated in **parts** first, and then the result of those parts are mapped as if by composition by another function?

Is it ever the case that given:

$f(x)=x' : x\mapsto x', \text{ }${ $x \land x' \in \mathbb{R}$ }

And:

$g(x)=x'' : x\mapsto x'', \text{ }${ $x \land x'' \in \mathbb{R}$ }

With:

$h(y)=y' : y\mapsto y', \text{ }${ $y \land y' \in \mathbb{R}$ }

One is **able** to evaluate:

$h(x' + x'')=y'' : (x' + x'')\mapsto y'', \text{ }${ $y'' \in \mathbb{R}$ }

But for some (whatever) reason, is **unable** to evaluate:

$h(f(x) + g(x))=y'' : (f(x)+g(x)) \mapsto y'', \text{ }${ $y'' \in \mathbb{R}$ }

Or put another way, a situation arising wherein (given the above definitions):

$h(f(x) + g(x)) \ne h(x' + x'')$

---

**Another possibility?**

I think what may happen however (and this is my fault for not suggesting this in the OP) is that one's able to **simplify** the expression when in the function form like: $h(f(x)+g(x)) \mapsto s(x)$ where $s(x)$ is a simplified (reduced) form of the composition of functions $h(f(x)+g(x))$.
It's this simplification step (which is only 'available' when the function is written out as a composition of functions) which must be **'throwing away information'** by, say, taking a preferred branch-cut which isn't taken when the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are evaluated first to get the real numbers $x'$ and $x''$ which are then evaluated as $h(x' + x'') = y''$ though $s(x) \ne y''$.

The existence of different branch-cuts (or other such things) would change the way 'composition of functions' work, given that then these 'functions' are not one-to-one (e.g. single valued) and thereby not functions (which goes to your point @5xum)...

I'm still curious if this can occur, where a reduced (or simplified) function gives a different answer than when it is written out in full supposing we're only dealing with algebraic manipulations to put our composition of functions into a simplified form?

---

Thanks for your answers and comments in advance!

Comment: No, because $h(x' + x'')$ is an ill-defined concept. The function $f$ you defined **does not know** that you call its output $x'$. The functions are objects that are independent of the names you give to their inputs and outputs. Thus, your expression $h(x'+x'')$ is not defined, while the expression $h(f(x)+g(x))$ is well defined, so you can't really compare the two.

Answer (score 3):

$h(x' + x'')$ is an ill-defined concept. The function $f$ you defined **does not know** that you call its output $x'$. The functions are objects that are independent of the names you give to their inputs and outputs. Thus, your expression $h(x'+x'')$ is not defined, while the expression $h(f(x)+g(x))$ is well defined, so you can't really compare the two.

---

What you have are three objects. $h$ is a function that takes **some real number**, and maps it to some other real number. So long as there is, for each number, *exactly one* number to which you map, then $h$ is a function.

Notice, I haven't used any variable names here. However, when defining functions, we usually want to introduce a free variable to explain what $h$ is doing, so we usually say, for example, $h(x)=x^2$. However we could also say that $h(y) = y^2$, and we would define **the exact same function** as before. However, the expression on the *right* of the equals sign must be an expression that gives **one and only one** answer to each value in the parentheses on the left side. So, if I say $h(x)=x^2$, I have defined a function because if I am given some $x$, I can calculate what $h(x)$ is.

What you did was you said that $h:y\mapsto y'$, which, without further definitions, doesn't really tell you anything except that $h$ is a function. Now, if you **define** $y'$ to equal $h(y)$, that's perfectly fine, but then if you also **define** $x'$ to be equal to $f(x)$ and $x''$ to be equal to $g(x)$, then the question

> Is $h(f(x)+g(x))=h(x'+x'')$

is trivial, since the answer is **yes, by definition**.